# Hilt migration for interface having multiple implementations and injected in one generic file constructor gives error: [Dagger/DuplicateBindings]

Tags: android, dependency-injection, interface, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

I am trying to migrate my existing Dagger implementation to Hilt.
I have one common interface which is implemented by multiple classes.

```
public interface SomeInterface {
void someMethod();}
```

Then there are implementation classes

```
public class First implements SomeInterface { 
@Inject
public First(
        @NonNull final SomeParam someParam){
    this.someParam = someParam;
}
 }

public class Second implements SomeInterface { 
@Inject
public Second(
        @NonNull final SomeParam someParam){
    this.someParam = someParam;}}
```

I have one presenter which has this interface injected in constructor and the presenter is in turn injected in one fragment

```
public class OnePresenter {
@Inject
public OnePresenter(SomeInterface interface) {}
```

Now, when I try to migrate this hierarchy using Hilt module, I am getting Duplicate Bindings error

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent.class)
public class InterfaceBindingModule {
@Provides
public SomeInterface getFirst(First first) {
    return (First) first;
}
@Provides
public SomeInterface getSecond(Second second) {
    return (Second) second;
}}
```

**error: [Dagger/DuplicateBindings] com.package.interface.SomeInterface is bound multiple times:**

Answer (score 0):

At the moment Dagger does not know what implementation of SomeInterface,  it needs to provide. You have two methods providing the same type SomeInterface. You need to distinguish them somehow.

Use Named annotation:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent.class)
public class InterfaceBindingModule {
@Provides
@Named("First")
public SomeInterface getFirst(First first) {
    return (First) first;
}
@Provides
@Named("Second")
public SomeInterface getSecond(Second second) {
    return (Second) second;
}}
```

And then declare which instance you want:

```
public class OnePresenter {
@Inject
public OnePresenter(@Named("First") SomeInterface interface) {}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have one concern for OnePresenter
```
public class OnePresenter {
@Inject
public OnePresenter(@Named("First") SomeInterface interface) {}
```

I want to pass the @Named("Second") as well at runtime to this constructor. Because if I specify only one Named then it won't work for the other @Named instance